# Broadcom STA Wireless Driver Fails to install

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I'm setting up a Dell M4400 Precision, and on previous installations I've merely installed the Broadcom STA Wireless Driver from the "Additional Drivers" app.  However with 11.04, I get this error: Sorry, installation of this driver failed.

Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log.

Which contains:

```
2011-05-26 19:18:33,726 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
2011-05-26 19:18:33,743 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
```

Wifi works fine on Windows, and had worked fine in Ubuntu 8.10-10.10.  I've done a fair amount of searching and tried quite a few fixes, all of them failed.

EDIT: After uncommenting the blacklist file I got the following errors in the var/log/jockey.log:

```
2011-06-01 12:49:13,283 DEBUG: updating <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB     instance at 0x9adfaec
2011-06-01 12:49:15,395 DEBUG: reading modalias file /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic-pae/modules.alias
2011-06-01 12:49:15,521 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/b43
2011-06-01 12:49:15,526 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/disable-upstream-nvidia
2011-06-01 12:49:15,554 WARNING: Could not open DriverDB cache /var/cache/jockey/driverdb-OpenPrintingDriverDB.cache: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/cache/jockey/driverdb-OpenPrintingDriverDB.cache'
2011-06-01 12:49:15,567 DEBUG: loading custom handler /usr/share/jockey/handlers/broadcom_wl.py
2011-06-01 12:49:15,627 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but would you consider using the B43 module? Does that even work?

Comment: This computer has b43 already installed it appears.. "firmware-b43-installer"

Comment: It looks like that module is blacklisted on your system. You'd need to uncomment it out (remove the proceeding #) in the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file to allow it to be loaded. You may wish to make a back-up of /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf first by doing `$ sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.bak`. This can be reversed by doing `$ sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.bak /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Comment: I followed your directions and uncommented it.. however I got the same error and the following in the var/log/jockey.log:

2011-06-01 12:49:13,283 DEBUG: updating <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x9adfaec>
2011-06-01 12:49:15,395 DEBUG: reading modalias file /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic-pae/modules.alias
2011-06-01 12:49:15,521 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/b43
2011-06-01 12:49:15,526 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/disable-upstream-nvidia

Comment: 2011-06-01 12:49:15,554 WARNING: Could not open DriverDB cache /var/cache/jockey/driverdb-OpenPrintingDriverDB.cache: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/cache/jockey/driverdb-OpenPrintingDriverDB.cache'
2011-06-01 12:49:15,567 DEBUG: loading custom handler /usr/share/jockey/handlers/broadcom_wl.py
2011-06-01 12:49:15,627 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl

Comment: Just visited my aunt... it appears that the most recent updates in Ubuntu 11.04 resolved the issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually have 2 Broadcom wireless cards in my laptop. What I do to get in working is:

`dpkg -l | grep b43` to find any b43 related packages to remove.

Then,

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source dkms
```

It has worked for me on every Ubuntu release I've used, including Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Unfortunately it's on my aunt's computer and I can't walk her through it for another week.  Going to give you the rep and hope it works.  Thanks mate!

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry for the late reply. Did it work out for you?

Comment: It unfortunately says "unable to locate package" when my aunt runs the second command ($ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source dkms).  Any suggestions? (she uninstalled two b43 packages in the previous steps, one named something like bccutter and one other..)  Sorry it's rather hard to know what's going on over the phone.

On the bright side, she now knows how to copy and paste! :)